# How can I extract a specific bit from a 16-bit register using math ONLY?

Tags: cpu-word, bit

I have a 16-bit WORD and I want to read the status of a specific bit or several bits.

I've tried a method that divides the word by the bit that I want, converts the result to two values - an integer and to a real, and compares the two.  if they are not equal, then it it equates to false.  This appears to only work if i am looking for a bit that the last 'TRUE' bit in the word.  If there are any successive TRUE bits, it fails.  Perhaps I just haven't done it right.  I don't have the ability to use code, just basic math, boolean operations, and type conversion.  Any ideas?  I hope this isn't a dumb question but i have a feeling it is.

eg:

WORD 0010000100100100 = 9348

I want to know the value of bit 2.  how can i determine it from 9348?

[image]

Comment: Exactly what do you want the answer to look like? Do you want that isolated bit in its original position, or in the least significant position?

Comment: Can you use bitwise AND, and shift operators?

Comment: I just added the functions that I have available as a screenshot to the original question.  I just need to be able to know if a bit is true or false.  The equation needs to result in a boolean value.  I can modify the equation as-needed to input which bit I want.

Comment: What answer do you get if you enter 1 AND 2? Also, what do you get if you enter 1 AND 3? That will help us know what the AND operator you have actually does. And the answer to that determines which of the answers below will work for you.

Comment: no dice on the bitwise AND :(   would have been an awesome solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, depending on what operations you can use. It appears you don't have much to choose from. But this should work, using just integer division and multiplication, and a test for equality.
(psuedocode):

```
x = 9348 (binary 0010000100100100, bit 0 = 0, bit 1 = 0, bit 2 = 1, ...)
x = x / 4 (now x is 1000010010010000
y = (x / 2) * 2 (y is 0000010010010000)
if (x == y) {
    (bit 2 must have been 0)
} else {
    (bit 2 must have been 1)
}
```

Every time you divide by 2, you move the bits to the left one position (in your big endian representation). Every time you multiply by 2, you move the bits to the right one position. Odd numbers will have 1 in the least significant position. Even numbers will have 0 in the least significant position. If you divide an odd number by 2 in integer math, and then multiply by 2, you loose the odd bit if there was one. So the idea above is to first move the bit you want to know about into the least significant position. Then, divide by 2 and then multiply by two. If the result is the same as what you had before, then there must have been a 0 in the bit you care about. If the result is not the same as what you had before, then there must have been a 1 in the bit you care about.

Having explained the idea, we can simplify to

```
((x / 8) * 2) <> (x / 4)
```

which will resolve to true if the bit was set, and false if the bit was not set.

Comment: So I'll reduce this to: 
((((9348/4))/2)*2) <> (((9348/4))/2))

Comment: The end result should evaluate to the status of bit 2 in this example.  - testing

Comment: No, I think it would be (((9348/4)/2)*2) <> (9348/4), or simplified further to just ((9348/8)*2) <> (9348/4)

Comment: Yeah my first attempt (above) was pretty obviously wrong :).  testing now!

Comment: I may be missing something..

9348 / 8 = 1168.5, *2 = 2337
9348 / 4 = 2337

they are equal, so the formula above evaluates to false.  but bit 2 was true..

Comment: It has to be integer division. It's hard to answer your question because we have no idea what system you are actually using.

Comment: ah because it's binary obviously

Comment: If you're dealing with rounding, and it always rounds .5 up, you can subtract 1 before you divide, and change the <> to an =, I think.

Answer (score 1):

AND the word with a mask [1].

In your example, you're interested in the second bit, so the mask (in binary) is
00000010.  (Which is 2 in decimal.)

In binary, your word 9348 is 0010010010000100 [2]

```
    0010010010000100 (your word)
AND 0000000000000010 (mask)
    ----------------
    0000000000000000 (result of ANDing your word and the mask)
```

Because the value is equal to zero, the bit is not set.  If it were different to zero, the bit was set.

This technique works for extracting one bit at a time.  You can however use it repeatedly with different masks if you're interested in extracting multiple bits.

[1] For more information on masking techniques see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

[2] See http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter

Comment: I don't think bitwise AND is available to him.

Comment: It's on the fourth row, first column of the image.

Comment: It wasn't clear if those were logical operators or bitwise operators, and I wasn't able to get clarification on that point from the OP.

Comment: Fair question.  You're right that the screenshot isn't clear.

Comment: I will test the AND function for fun - thought i bet it's boolean only.  This is on an HMI for a manufacturing process control system - I have 'WORD' tags coming from our PLCs to our SCADAS with lots of status bits for each individual piece of equipment, but I only need to represent one status bit on the screen.. the rest are only used in the PLC.  Historically, we would just create an additional tag in the SCADA that wold reference the bit directly from the PLC word (Register:bit)

Comment: I'm cleaning up the system and removing bloat, and if the HMI can extract a single bit from the SCADA tag, that is better IMO.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the HMI creation software doesn't have a bit extraction ability?  The tools I've used in the same vein provided such a feature.  If it's not available that's a pretty major omission!  Another possible approach is that if you're extracting the data from the PLCs via Modbus you might be able to do this in a bit-wise fashion.

Comment: no dice on the bitwise AND :(   would have been an awesome solution!

The HMI/SCADA package i am using is called GE Proficy iFIX and is actually very robust.. the HMI can only deal with SCADA tags and perform the basic logic in the screenshot to the tags.  This actually allows a lot of flexibilty, though you have to get a bit creative with the math.  The SCADAs absolutely DO have bit extraction capability by simply appending the end of the register with the desired bit (401222:3).  This is the way we currently do it - we just create a new digital SCADA tag with the desired bit and use that...

Comment: tag in the HMI.  But I'm a big fan of efficiency where possible, so I don't like a bunch of additional tags just to extract specific bits.  The approach I have been using works, and is almost identical  to hatchets proposed answer - The downside is that I was getting the math wrong - thinking it was turning the results of REAL division into integers (rounds up) instead of doing actual INTEGER division, which after some investigation, it turns out it IS doing by way of (INT (TAG/BIT)).  Perhaps you can see how the syntax confused me.

Comment: no dice on the bitwise AND :( would have been an awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

The nth bit is equal to the word divided by 2^n mod 2

I think you'll have to test each bit, 0 through 15 inclusive.

Comment: This seems to lend credence to my original technique which compares two results (one real, one int - no remainder) of a division operation with the original WORD and the decimal value of the desired bit position:

( ( ( ( ( INT ( 9348 / 4 ) ) / 2 ) - ( INT ( ( INT ( 9348 / 4 ) ) / 2 ) ) <> 0 )

but it just doesn't seem to work if there are more-significant bits in the WORD

Comment: @goofology Yeah, the mod two is there to ignore the more significant bits.  It doesn't look like you are allowed to use mod though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 9348 AND 4 (equivalent of 1<<2 - index of the bit you wanted)

```
9348 AND 4
```

should give 4 if bit is set, 0 if not.

Comment: I was under the impression that he did not have bitwise and nor bit shifting available to him.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think bitwise is available to him as i see XOR there

Comment: no dice on the bitwise AND :(   would have been an awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I have come up with:  3 solutions.  One is Hatchet's as proposed above, and his answer helped me immensely with actually understanding HOW this works, which is of utmost importance to me!  The proposed AND masking solutions could have worked if my system supports bitwise operators, but it apparently does not.

Original technique:

```
( ( ( INT ( TAG / BIT ) ) / 2 ) - ( INT ( ( INT ( TAG / BIT ) ) / 2 ) ) <> 0 )
```

Explanation:
in the first part of the equation, integer division is performed on TAG/BIT, then REAL division by 2.  In the second part, integer division is performed TAG/BIT, then integer division again by 2.  The difference between these two results is compared to 0.  If the difference is not 0, then the formula resolves to TRUE, which means the specified bit is also TRUE.

eg: 9348/4 = 2337 w/ integer division. Then 2337/2 = 1168.5 w/ REAL division but 1168 w/ integer division.  1168.5-1168 <> 0, so the result is TRUE.

My modified technique:

```
( INT ( TAG / BIT ) / 2 ) <> ( INT ( INT ( TAG / BIT ) / 2 ) )
```

Explanation:
effectively the same as above, but instead of subtracting the two results and comparing them to 0, I am just comparing the two results themselves.  If they are not equal, the formula resolves to TRUE, which means the specified bit is also TRUE.

eg: 9348/4 = 2337 w/ integer division. Then 2337/2 = 1168.5 w/ REAL division but 1168 w/ integer division.  1168.5 <> 1168, so the result is TRUE.

Hatchet's technique as it applies to my system:

```
( INT ( TAG / BIT )) <> ( INT ( INT ( TAG / BIT ) / 2 ) * 2 )
```

Explanation:
in the first part of the equation, integer division is performed on TAG/BIT.  In the second part, integer division is performed TAG/BIT, then integer division again by 2, then multiplication by 2.  The two results are compared.  If they are not equal, the formula resolves to TRUE, which means the specified bit is also TRUE.

eg: 9348/4 = 2337. Then 2337/2 = 1168 w/ integer division. Then 1168x2=2336.   2337 <> 2336 so the result is TRUE.  As Hatchet stated, this method 'drops the odd bit'.

---

Note - 9348/4 = 2337 w/ both REAL and integer division, but it is important that these parts of the formula use integer division and not REAL division (12164/32 = 380 w/ integer division and 380.125 w/ REAL division)

I feel it important to note for any future readers that the BIT value in the equations above is not the bit number, but the actual value of the resulting decimal if the bit in the desired position was the only TRUE bit in the binary string (bit 2 = 4 (2^2), bit 6 = 64 (2^6))

This explanation may be a bit too verbatim for some, but may be perfect for others :)

Please feel free to comment/critique/correct me if necessary!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to resolve an integer status code to a bit state in order to interface with some hardware.  Here's a method that works for me:

```
private bool resolveBitState(int value, int bitNumber)
{
    return (value & (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) != 0;
}
```

I like it, because it's non-iterative, requires no cast operations and essentially translates directly to machine code operations like Shift, And and Comparison, which probably means it's really optimal.

To explain in a little more detail, I'm comparing the bitwise value to a mask for the bit I am interested in (value & mask) using an AND operation.  If the bitwise AND operation result is zero, then the bit is not set (return false).  If the AND operation result is not zero, then the bit is set (return true).  The result of the AND operation is either zero or the value of the bit (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...). Hence the boolean evaluation comparing the AND operation result and 0.  The mask is created by taking the number 1 and shifting it left (bit wise), by the appropriate number of binary places (1 << n). The number of places is the number of the bit targeted minus 1.  If it's bit #1, I want to shift the 1 left by 0 and if it's #2, I want to shift it left 1 place, etc.

I'm surprised no one rates my solution.  It think it's most logical and succinct... and works.